# Expand the selection around multiple active cells using VBA macros in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly simple request in Excel using VBA, but I can't think of a way to do it, and I can't find any solutions online.

I have selected multiple columns, and I want to use a macro to expand the selection either side of each selected column.

So for instance I have highlighted columns G, K and Z, and I want to be able to have highlighted F-H, J-L, and Y-AA.

Hope that makes sense, many thanks!

Comment: Try [`Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) perhaps?

Comment: Needs an offset too I think for the left adjacency `Selection.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 3).Select`

Comment: Ah unfortunately this only works with single selections, I think, not when you have multiple columns selected

Comment: What do you want to do with the selected cells/ranges?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not supposed to answer questions that don't have code examples but this question is impossible to solve without a lot of experience working with ranges.

- Outer Loop (`Area`): Iterate through each Area in `Selection.Areas`
- Inner Loop (`Item`): Iterate all the Column references
- Create a New Range that references the `Area.EntireRow.Columns(Item)
- If the Target is Nothing: Set Target = NewRange
- Else Set Target = Union(Target, NewRange )

### Demo

### [image: Expand Selection]

```
Sub TestExpandRange()
    Application.Goto ExpandRange(Selection, "H", "J:L", "Y:AA")
End Sub

Function ExpandRange(Source As Range, ParamArray ColumnArgs() As Variant) As Range
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim NewRange As Range
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim Item As Variant
    
    For Each Area In Source.Areas
        For Each Item In ColumnArgs
            Set NewRange = Area.EntireRow.Columns(Item)
            If Target Is Nothing Then
                Set Target = NewRange
            Else
                Set Target = Union(Target, NewRange)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    Set ExpandRange = Target
End Function
```

### Edit 1

This will add the extra columns to the Selection

```
Function ExpandRange2(Source As Range, ParamArray ColumnArgs() As Variant) As Range
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim NewRange As Range
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim Item As Variant
    Set Target = Source
    
    For Each Area In Source.Areas
        For Each Item In ColumnArgs
            Set NewRange = Area.EntireRow.Columns(Item)
            Set Target = Union(Target, NewRange)
        Next
    Next
    
    Set ExpandRange2 = Target
End Function
```

### Edit 2

```
Sub SelectAdjacentColumns()
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim NewRange As Range
    Dim Area As Range
    
    For Each Area In Selection.Areas
        If Area.Column = 1 Then
            Set NewRange = Area.Resize(, 2).EntireColumn
        ElseIf Area.Column = Columns.Count Then
            Set NewRange = Area.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2).EntireColumn
        Else
            Set NewRange = Area.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 3).EntireColumn
        End If
        
        If Target Is Nothing Then
            Set Target = NewRange
        Else
            Set Target = Union(Target, NewRange)
        End If
    Next
    
    Target.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, this doesn't really solve it - I don't think I explained my issue properly though: I'm trying to expand the selection around a large number of colums

Comment: @ReubenLong It is a little unclear to me what you want to do.  Let me know if you update your question. I added Edit 1 to include the original range in the selection.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to edit that. Here's what I meant to say:

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, this doesn't really solve it - I don't think I explained my issue properly though: I'm trying to expand the selection around a large number of columns which contain the values I want and which I'll select by searching for them using CTRL+F. I'm also trying to do the same thing on multiple sheets. So it's not really feasible to do it by naming the columns to expand the range around: I really just want to be able to do it around the active cells / columns

Comment: @ReubenLong  I miss read the original post. Suppose you are interested in Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3.  If you have G, K and Z selected do you want columns F:H, J:L, and Y:AA on just Sheet1 or on all three worksheets?  You are selecting entire columns correct?

Comment: Essentially what I want to do it select every column that contains a certain value and then select columns either side of those columns, and I need to do this for hundreds of columns over multiple sheets, hence why I think I need to use CTRL+F and select using active cells. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ReubenLong It does but do you want the same selection on all the worksheets or do you want to do it a sheet at a time?

Comment: One sheet at a time - each sheet contains different columns, so the selection will be different

Comment: @ReubenLong Edit 2 should do what you want.  Note: You can select single cells or columns.